# Is there a way to drop(paste) file in to the directory using the keyboard?

Tags: windows-10, file-transfer, file-management, copy-paste, drag-and-drop

I'm organizing a lot of files and directories,

so for example,

within directory A there is directory B, C and file X, Y

DIR A - DIR B

```
  - DIR C

  - file X

  - file Y

  - file Z
```

I want to move file X, Y in to DIR B,

method 1. select files, and then drag and drop with mouse

method2. select files, cut those files (ctrl-x) and then go in DIR B, paste those files (ctrl-v) inside

---

since there are so many dir & files (100s & 1000s), method 1 using manual mouse control

is somewhat tiresome, so I want to use the keyboard mostly

I want to use methode 2 but directly pasting on the DIR-B (by selecting it and ctrl-v on it)

doesn't work, that you should go inside the actual DIR-B, then post.

---

is there a way to directly 'paste inside the DIR-B' by keyboard shortcuts,

without going inside the actual directory, but by selecting it only?

---

is there a good 'file manager' software that is useful for these kind of keyboard oriented inteface?

Comment: Does right-click the directory and choose paste from the menu work?  If so, then you can activate the context menu from the keyboard (if you have a 104 key), the context menu key should be between the right Alt and Ctrl.

Comment: thank you & yes, I think the most close way is to 
select the directory -> right click for menu (shortcut seems "shift f10", , i don't have direct button in my keyboard) -> click paste (press "p" 3 times and "enter")

i have not found a direct shortcut key for pasting the file into the highlighted folder or folder shorcut, or any file manager program which supports such functionality without going into each folder for pasting

Answer (score 1):

In Windows Explorer, type the following into the address bar:

shell:sendto

That will open a special folder in the path C:\Users\username\AppData\Roaming\Microsoft\Windows\SendTo

In there, make a shortcut to the directory you want to copy to, such as DIR-B.

After that, you can go to the location of your files that you want to copy.  Select them, and right-click.  In the pop-up menu, you should see "Send to >".  When you mouse over that, a sub-menu will appear, and DIR-B should be one of the options.  Just click on it, and it will copy the selected files to that location.

Comment: thank you for your reply~!
your reply is a good tip, like using multiple folder shortcuts.
so there are no direct keyboard shortcuts to paste in the highlighted
folder or folder shortcut, I guess? (other than right click, and paste
or "send to")

Comment: Just *sendto* works. You can now type all sorts of stuff in Explorer's address bar, like *startup*, *desktop*, *programs*, *program files*, *recycle bin*, and even *cmd*, *control*, *notepad*, *regedit*, *msinfo32*, ...